# How can I fill inbetween these Green/Red Lines?

Tags: line, gradient, pine-script, fill

I can't for the life of me figure out how to fill in between these horizontal lines.
I currently have 2 horizontal lines, & would love to fill them in with color or a gradient.

It's not the normal code, as these are formatted line.new...

Anyone knows how?

I would love to color these zones with a gradient, but can't figure out how to tell the code these exact horizontal lines

```
//@version=4

study(shorttitle = "[CC] Price Zone", title="[CC] Price Zone", overlay=true, max_bars_back=500)

// ●─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── ∴ ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────● }

maxBarsBack = 500

line bullEngulfOpen = na
line bullEngulfLow = na
//line bullEngulf50 = na

line bearEngulfOpen = na
line bearEngulfHigh = na
//line bearEngulf50 = na

previousRange = open[1] - close[1]
isBullEngulf = previousRange > 0 and close > open[1]
isBearEngulf = previousRange < 0 and close < open[1]

//colors//
coloropen = color.rgb(76,187,23,30)
colorwick = color.rgb(194,24,7,10)

if isBullEngulf
    bullEngulfOpen := line.new(bar_index - 1, open[1], bar_index, open[1], extend=extend.right, color=coloropen)
    bullEngulfLow := line.new(bar_index - 1, low < low[1] ? low : low[1],bar_index, low < low[1] ? low : low[1], extend=extend.right, color=colorwick)
    //bullEngulf50 := line.new(bar_index - 1, ((high[1]+low[1])/2), bar_index, ((high[1]+low[1])/2), extend=extend.right, color=color.blue, style=line.style_dotted)

if isBearEngulf
    bearEngulfOpen := line.new(bar_index - 1, open[1], bar_index, open[1], extend=extend.right, color=coloropen)
    bearEngulfHigh := line.new(bar_index - 1, high > high[1] ? high : high[1], bar_index, high > high[1] ? high : high[1], extend=extend.right, color=colorwick)
   // bearEngulf50 := line.new(bar_index - 1, ((low[1]+high[1])/2), bar_index, ((low[1]+high[1])/2), extend=extend.right, color=color.fuchsia, style=line.style_dotted)

//color gray when finished//
grayopen = color.rgb(49,51,53,10)
graywick = color.rgb(84,86,88,10)

var maxNumberOfEngulfings = 10
bullEngulfingCount = 0
for i = 1 to maxBarsBack
    if not na(bullEngulfOpen[i])
        if low < line.get_y1(bullEngulfLow[i])
            line.delete(bullEngulfOpen[i])
            line.delete(bullEngulfLow[i])
           // line.delete(bullEngulf50[i])
            continue
        if low < line.get_y1(bullEngulfOpen[i])
            line.set_color(bullEngulfOpen[i], grayopen)
            line.set_color(bullEngulfLow[i], graywick)
           // line.set_color(bullEngulf50[i], color.gray)
            
        bullEngulfingCount := bullEngulfingCount + 1
        if bullEngulfingCount > maxNumberOfEngulfings
            line.delete(bullEngulfOpen[i])
            line.delete(bullEngulfLow[i])
           // line.delete(bullEngulf50[i])
            
bearEngulfingCount = 0
for i = 1 to maxBarsBack   
    if not na(bearEngulfOpen[i])
        if high > line.get_y1(bearEngulfHigh[i])
            line.delete(bearEngulfOpen[i])
            line.delete(bearEngulfHigh[i])
           // line.delete(bearEngulf50[i])
            continue
        if high > line.get_y1(bearEngulfOpen[i])
            line.set_color(bearEngulfOpen[i], grayopen)
            line.set_color(bearEngulfHigh[i], graywick)
           // line.set_color(bearEngulf50[i], color.gray) 
            
        bearEngulfingCount := bearEngulfingCount + 1
        if bearEngulfingCount > maxNumberOfEngulfings
            line.delete(bearEngulfOpen[i])
            line.delete(bearEngulfHigh[i])
           // line.delete(bearEngulf50[i])
```

Comment: Is this python?

Comment: You should tag your question with the programming language it is written in. Most users review the tag pages for languages they are proficient in rather than the front page.